# CSS layout with two rows, two columns

Tags: css

Helllo, Im stuck... because whatever I do it is not working. I have the following layout:

```
<body>
<div id = "Container">
    <div id = "Header">
        <div id = "Logo"></div>
        <div id = "Header-Pannel"></div>
</div>

    <div id = "Body">
        <div id = "Left"></div>
        <div id = "Right"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I need is to make:

```
body and Container 100% width, oriented top-left

#Logo {width 180px; height 180px;} - fixed width
#Header-Pannel {height: 180px} - width is 100% space between logo and right edge of the window, fluid width

#Left {fluid width, 100% of space between left edge of the window and right block}
#Right {width: 180px}
```

Im not including my current css, because it became messy after countless attempts. Can someone give me a solution?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: define not working please

Comment: this has to be very simple, few lines of css, so every time Im trying to add or change a line, I cant get the desired result... Im trying relative positions, negative margins and so on... Im just stack

Comment: can you make a small sketch please to show us your desired result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your question is not clear that what you want but this may help you:

```css
body { width: 100%; margin: 0; }
#Container { width: 100%; min-height: 300px; }
#Logo {width 180px; height 180px; float: left;}
#Header-Pannel {width: according to your need; height: 180px; float: right;}
#Left {width: according to your need, min-height: 100px; float: left;}
#Right {width: 180px; min-height: 100px; float: right;}
```

Comment: Ok, ask me if the problem prevails.

Comment: Wait. Multiple errors in this CSS. `foat` > `float` , `fluid width` ?